# How to mark beginning and ending of a footnote

Tags: footnotes

I'm trying to typeset an Indian Bare Act in Latex. I am facing problem with Footnotes.

This is how they look: (see page 39 for [PDF version](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/bitstream/123456789/2263/1/aA1860-45.pdf))

[image]

So, I'm looking for

1. a way to mark the opening &  closing of `[` & `]`
2. nesting of these

These both would allow me to typeset as shown, but I want to slightly improve upon the design a bit.

3. While reading, its difficult to match which closing `]` corresponds to which opening `[` so I'd like to have a superscript footnote number on the closing `]` too.
4. I'd like the formatting (color, typeface, font-size) to be customizable, so that I can maintain certain visual distinction between the text and footnote markings.

I'm guessing  syntax like this should do:

```
\begin{footnotefor}
This text is being footnoted.
\footnote{This is the actual footnote}
\end{footnotefor}
```

All of these are what I want but I don't have a clue how to proceed.

Comment: It will be easier for all of us if you can add code to your question, which compiles. Kindly follow this procedure, if necessary, to arrive at a compact yet complete example we'd like to see here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790

Comment: You could highlight the text being referenced.  Unless this is some obscure legal noataion.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I didn't understand what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solves 1 and 2 (provided I understand correctly what you mean by "nesting"):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[height=2in,width=3in]{geometry} %Just to produce reasonably sized PDF for the screencap

\newcommand\footnotefor[2]{\footnote{#1}[#2]}

\begin{document}
Outside the footnote. \footnotefor{First footnote, should be 1}{Some text \footnotefor{Second footnote, should be 2}{An object deserving a footnote} and some other text \footnotefor{Third footnote, should be 3}{Some text, but behold \footnotefor{Fourth footnote, should be 4}{innermost object}}}. 
\end{document}
```

To add 3 to it requires a little more work

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[height=2in,width=3in]{geometry} %Just to produce reasonably sized PDF for the screencap

\newcommand\footnotefor[2]{\bgroup\footnote{#1}\edef\tmpfnmk{\arabic{footnote}}[#2]\footnotemark[\tmpfnmk]\egroup}

\begin{document}
Outside the footnote. \footnotefor{First footnote, should be 1}{Some text \footnotefor{Second footnote, should be 2}{An object deserving a footnote} and some other text \footnotefor{Third footnote, should be 3}{Some text, but behold \footnotefor{Fourth footnote, should be 4}{innermost object}}}. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: As to item 4: to change colors you can just load `xcolor` and `\renewcommand\thefootnote{{\color{red}\arabic{footnote}}}` or similar, and I don't really see the point of changing typeface (of single character) or size.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a savior. I'm a latex beginner, I was really doubtful if I'd be able to do this on my own.   About 4. Even I don't know if changing typeface is desirable but I'm hoping changing the color (as in making it slightly greyish) should enhance reading experience.